# feature request in language design?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, language-features

How do language designers decide when a *`feature`* should go in a library as an extension or when it needs to have support from the core language?

Comment: This should probably be on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: please move it..

Comment: Also, I doubt there is any single answer; but: cost of time to implement, necessity, usefulness, complexity, "gut", time scales, release schedules, whim, ...

Comment: @Marc do all your points apply to opensource languages as well?

Comment: why wouldn't it? all the factors are the same...

Comment: In particular complexity (that it adds to the language) and usefulness (of language-level support as opposed to a library). Necessity and usefulness (of the feature in general) decide whether to implement it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not read language designer's blogs?

http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/

http://nighthacks.com/roller/jag/entry/time_to_move_on

I'm sure you could find some language designers and read their blogs.

Also, for many languages under active development, there are wikis, discussion forms and -- in some cases -- a formal "community" process.  All of which you can read.

http://jcp.org/en/home/index

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/

These aren't hard to find.